# How to evenly split d3 links between circles

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have the following data set

```
var data = { nodes: 
   [ { addr: '1',
       address: '1',
       x: 100,
       y: 200 },
     { addr: '2',
       address: '2',
       x: 200,
       y: 0 },
     { addr: '3',
       address: '3',
       x: 200,
       y: 150 },
     { addr: '4', address: '4', x: 200, y: 240 },
     { addr: '5', address: '5', x: 200, y: 360 }
  ],
  links: 
   [ { source: 0, target: 1 },
     { source: 0, target: 2 },
     { source: 0, target: 3 },
     { source: 0, target: 4 } ] }
```

Which currently looks like this:

[image]

I'm trying to find a formula that will allow me to calculate the correct Y value for any given number of circles (within reason, the formula should work if there are 1, 2 or even 10 circles).

I'm trying to get to something like this:

[image]

That will look symmetrical.

My X and Y for the first circle (in blue) are known and are static.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula for calculating y-coordinate for ith circle in the column could be like this if you would like to define it with circle radius and spacing:

```
Yith = Y+[i-(n+1)/2]*(diameter+padding)
```

Where *Y* is the y-coordinate of the first (blue) circle, *i* is ith circle in the column, *n* represents number of circles in column and *(diameter+padding)* are shown on the image. It represents diameter of the ball with spacing.

[image]